# Initialization of a Repository with access and refresh token obtained from /Sn-out/login? provider=my_name

Tags: oauth, sensenet

I have a problem with initializing a Repository from sn-client-js. I'm using a custom OAuth provider and I successfully received an object with the access and the refresh token.

Now I want to initialize a Repository and use it to list and modify user content, but I do not know how to provide tokens to repository object.

Comment: Please provide your code, what you tried and where you are facing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Login states belongs to repository instances, so repositories should be used as singletons.

1. create the repository instance
2. configure JWT
3. register OAuth provider
4. login on the repository instance (or the repository's own authentication provider)

and you will get a proper user and session.

I think you should use [scoped @sensenet packages](https://community.sensenet.com/blog/2018/02/21/scoped-packages) instead of sn-client-js.